# What is the intuitive difference between covariance and the product of the standard deviations of bivariate data?

Tags: statistics, covariance, correlation, standard-deviation

Can someone help me understand what the difference is—intuitively—between these concepts? Here's how I currently think of these things.

The covariance, represented by:

[image]

... is essentially a mean area, in standard units, representing the average "size" of the joint variation from the variables' respective means.

But the product of the standard deviations ($\sigma_x\cdot\sigma_y$) seems to encapsulate this exact same idea—the average area of the joint variation from the variables' respective means.

How do I distinguish these ideas conceptually?

Edit to add:

If the correlation coefficient (r) is the ratio $\frac{cov_{xy}}{\sigma_x\cdot\sigma_y}$, then what does this ratio embody, i.e., how many whats of what?

Comment: $\sigma_x\sigma_y$ is invariant under the joint distribution of $x,y$

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, can you elaborate on that? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If you divide the covariance by the product of the standard deviations, you should get the correlation.  This is a number between $-1$ and $1$ and has no units and is a ratio related to the linear relationship between the two variables.

Comment: @Henry I understand that. I guess what I'm looking for is: whoever invented r (Pearson, I'm guessing) had an idea, an intuition. He thought, "Hey, this ratio is useful, because ___. One term represents ___ and the other term represents ___, and knowing this will tell me about a relationship between these variables." What is the idea, in English, not mathematical notation?

Comment: I prefer [pictures to get a sense of correlations](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Correlation_examples2.svg/506px-Correlation_examples2.svg.png).  The division by the standard deviations removes the scaling effect of the dispersions of the two variables

Comment: In an inner product space, one defines the angle $\theta$ between two vectors $u,v$ as $\arccos \frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\|u\| \|v\|}$. This generalizes the notion of angles in $\mathbb R^2$, where you know that $$\langle u,v\rangle = \|u\|\|v\|\cos \theta$$ Since random variables constitute an inner product space, the correlation coefficient $r$ can be thought of as as a number which represents the angle between two random variables, and consequently, also the strength of the linear relationship between two random variables.

Comment: In formulae, $$ r \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}\frac{E\, XY}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$$ , where $X,Y$ are random variables on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. Defining the vector space $L^2 = \{X: \int X^2 \,dP<\infty\}$ with inner product $\langle X,Y\rangle = \int XY\,dP$, one sees that $$r = \frac{\langle X,Y\rangle}{\|X\| \|Y\|}$$ And given $(X_1,Y_1),\dots,(X_n,Y_n)$ which are i.i.d as $(X,Y)$, then you can define the plug in estimator $$\hat r = \frac{E_{(X,Y)\sim \mu} XY}{\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}_{X\sim \nu_X}(X)\mathrm{Var}_{Y\sim \nu_Y}}(Y)}$$

Comment: Where $\mu,\nu_X,\nu_Y$ are the empirical distributions. Namely, $$ \mu = n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{(X_i,Y_i)},\quad \nu_X = n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{X_i}$$ and similarly for $\nu_Y$.